# Reverse proxy apache redirecting to client localhost

Tags: docker, apache2, reverse-proxy

I am trying to redirect traffic from Apache2 to a Docker container. I have the following configuration on my site.conf:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8000/
<Proxy *>
Allow from localhost
</Proxy>
```

However, this redirects the browser to the client's localhost, not to the server's. Anything I am missing here?

Comment: did you find a solution to this? If so can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Have you exposed the 8000 port from the docker container? using -p flag?

Comment: Yes. I can curl to it and all. As I said, the problem is that the proxy redirects to the client’s local host.